# How to enforce webkit to use system APN proxy in Android?

Tags: android, proxy, webkit, apn

I'm trying to force Webkit to use proxy definde in APN.

My proxy configuration:

```
APN: wap
PROXY: 192.168.6.102
PORT: 8080
USER: wap
PASSWORD: wap`
```

Currently all connections made by Webkit are blocked on firewall.  Is there way to use proxy from phone profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there are bugs in Android preventing this

APN proxy http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9126  (Fixed in Froyo)
Wifi proxy http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273